# Meaning of "Core" as a member name suffix

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

*Note: I just want to say up front this is a very minor question - purely a curiosity.*

What is the meaning when a member is named with a suffix "Core"?

Other examples of members using the "Core" suffix off the top:

- SearchCore
- SortCore

I just came across it in the [WAF framework](http://waf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Model-View-ViewModel%20Pattern&referringTitle=Home) and have a theory - could it come from the visual cue that the type name between <>'s (which is the type of the member `ViewCore`) making it look like a "core" of sorts?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Core` is usually used as a keyword when you are looking at the very fundamentals of a class. In general these classes contains the very basics of the application, relaying on the bare minimum dependencies to make it easy to use the code throughout your application, or other applications.

Comment: To be honest that is at least how I define `Core`, from working with the `MVVM` pattern. I base this on internal documents we use to create tools, so I don't have an external source unfortunately.

Comment: No problem at all, I was just curious.  You're writing style is kind of (this is meant to be a complement) academic :)

Comment: Yeah, you see the same thing at times with `Impl`, `Inner`, etc. - just a word to signify "these are the details, you shouldn't need to know about them"

Answer (score 5):

In section 9.9 Template Method (p.355) of "Framework Design Guidelines" by Krzysztif Cwalina and Brad Abrams states:

*Consider naming protected virtual members that provide extensibility points for nonvirtual members by suffixing the nonvirtual member name with "Core".*

```
public void SetBounds(...) {
    ...
    SetBoundsCore(...); // [Extension Point]
}
protected virtual void SetBoundsCore(...){...}
```

The template method patter allows you to preserve execution logic and control certain pre and post behaviors after a derived class executes the extension method.